# How to iterate over several columns in a data frame and assign a new column value based on info in several others

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Newbie here..but very enthusiastic. I have a lot of survey data where I have to derive a value in a newly created column in a dataframe based on where there are 0's or 1's in multiple other columns.

```
dftest = pd.DataFrame({'connection_0': ['0', '1','0','0','1'], 'connection_1': ['1', '0','1','1','0']},index=['819', '820','821','822','823'])
```

so here's what it looks like:

```
    connection_0 connection_1
819           0            1
820           1            0
821           0            1
822           0            1
823           1            0
```

And I want to add a column 'connect' before and set the value of that column to either "none" if connection_0 is '1' or "patient" if connection_1 is '1'. I actually have many more than two columns of these (connection_2, etc) but I can handle that later. I also have thousands of rows of data so this is just a test data frame.

Here's what I want-

```
    connect connection_0 connection_1
819    patient         0            1
820    none            1            0
821    patient         0            1
822    patient         0            1
823    none            1            0
```

Here's my attempt that sort of works but it sets all 'connect' to 'none'

for index, row in dftest.iterrows():

```
if row[0]=="1": row.connect=row.connect.replace('1', 'none')

else: 
    if row[0]=="0" & row[1]=="1":row.connect=row.connect.replace('1', 'patient')
```

But I get this:

```
        connect connection_0 connection_1
819    none            0            1
820    none            1            0
821    none            0            1
822    none            0            1
823    none            1            0
```

I know I'm doing something really stupid so any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code**

If you need to add similar operations to other columns instead of two columns, it seems that using `np.select` is the best way. You can increase the number of columns to be applied by adding `cond#`.

```
import numpy as np
cond1 = dftest['connection_0'].eq('1')
cond2 = dftest['connection_1'].eq('1')
arr = np.select([cond1, cond2], ['none', 'patient'])
out = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=['connect'], index=dftest.index).join(dftest)
```

out:

```
    connect connection_0    connection_1
819 patient 0               1
820 none    1               0
821 patient 0               1
822 patient 0               1
823 none    1               0
```

---

Make it more concise :

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.select(dftest.eq('1').T.values, ['none', 'patient'])
out = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=['connect'], index=dftest.index).join(dftest)
```

---

If all columns contain '1', it is also possible to do it in the following way.

Let's make a dictionary that assigns the value to be assigned when '1' for each column and assign it to `m`.

```
m = {'connection_0':'none', 'connection_1':'patient'}
dftest.eq('1').idxmax(axis=1).map(m).to_frame('connect').join(dftest)
```

Comment: perfect! thank you so much Panda Kim!  Works like a charm with another condition!

Comment: @pyphan I'm glad it was resolved, but then you need to select an answer for the next people.